# php symfony controller doesn't get the id but the object while calling only the id

Tags: php, symfony

I have a form that I submit and I parse the data through controller.

I want to extract the Id to pass it to my route and delete that related item.
I use form->getData() and when I pass the variable to which I assigned this form->getData() it returns an error message (Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given)..., here is my controller:

```
public function newGroupAction(Request $request)
    {
        $group = new TricksGroup();

        $form = $this->createForm(TricksGroupType::class, $group);

        $form->handleRequest($request);
```

> here is the issue:

```
        **if($form->getClickedButton() && 'Remove' === $form->getClickedButton()->getName()) {

            $id = $form->get('groupId')->getData();

            dump($id);

            return $this->redirectToRoute('oc_prep_delgroup', array('id' => $id));**
        }
```

> here is fine, the issue is the code above

```
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($group);
            $em->flush();

            $this->addFlash('success', 'Group created successfully!');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('oc_prep_add');
        }

        return $this->render('OCPrepBundle:Default:newgroup.html.twig', [

            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

I dumped the $id to see what it brings and indeed the object is assigned to it... while I just want this id:
[here is the print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgkeb.png)

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so I found the solution here.
I first had  to call the method $form->getData()->getGroupId();
and passing it to an array:

$id[] = $form->getData()->getGroupId();

Then I looped through the array to get the value of the groupId that I was looking for and then I passed the result in my route to generate the related url.

```
if($form->getClickedButton() && 'Remove' === $form->getClickedButton()->getName()) {

            if (!$form->isSubmitted() || !$form->isValid()){

                $this->addFlash('error', 'Invalid form please try again!');


            }
            $id[] = $form->getData()->getGroupId();

            foreach ($id as $idreturned){

                $x = $idreturned->getGroupId();

            }
                return $this->redirectToRoute('oc_prep_delgroup', array('id' => $x));

        }
```

Now if anyone as an idea to optimize it I'll be happy to hear from you.
But that's weird though that this $form->getData()->getGroupId(); returns the full object still don't really understand to be really honest...
If anyone can explain I'll be happy to approve your answer even though I found the solution to my initial question :)

Answer (score 0):

Form getData method should return the form's submitted values, so then you need to call the getter for the id... something along the lines of:

`$id = $form->getData()->getGroupId();`

Comment: looking at your screenshot it looks like getData is giving you the expected data... might be an issue with the getter on the `TricksGroup` entity?

Comment: I just have a getId() (actually it is getGroupId()) generated by doctrine, weird that it does that, maybe ill use a loop to fetch the data and extract the id...?

Comment: The entity should have a getter and setter for each property. IIRC the generate entity command can do this for you; see https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_entity.html#usage

Comment: Yes this is how I actually generated this class/entity.

Comment: I have the getters and setters, but here it's more related to what's being fetched from $form->getData()->getGroupId(), I still don't understand why is giving me the full object rather than the id only...?